# Override exception handler on comments throttling. Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

In `__construct()` method I added `$this->middleware('throttle:1,1');` for preventing too frequent comments. As I send more that one comment per minute, I get error 429. Debugbar says this:

```
 return is_callable($responseCallback)
                ? new HttpResponseException($responseCallback($request, $headers))
                : new ThrottleRequestsException('Too Many Attempts.', null, $headers);
```

But I don't need error page. I want to make this message looks like a validation error — with displaying text "too many attempts" in the comment form.

And also, this restriction should not apply to authorized users. It's only for guests. Should I write method for checking authorization with applying throttle, or maybe there is more shorter in-built way, that I can use right in `__construct()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is my solution. In App\Exceptions\Handler I added this:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->renderable(function (ThrottleRequestsException $e) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'You post comments too often');
    });
}
```

And in form view:

```
  @if (session('message'))
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {{ session('message') }}
        </div>
  @endif
```

For the admin and guests separation I created second method in CommentController. Default method for saving comments is `store()`, and method special for admin — `storeForAdmin()`. So, `__contstruct()` method looks like this:

```
$this->middleware('throttle:1,1')->except('storeForAdmin');
```

Not the best way, because I don't know, how to edit existing middleware from vendors, but it works anyway.

Comment: Well, you will get the same error message (You post comments too often) for all other requests as well. I don't think so this one is the right one. I am also looking for the generic so it should look like a validation error as my entire form has disappeared and Laravel default 429 error page render.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
use \Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;

protected $maxAttempts = 1;
protected $decayMinutes = 1;

public function newComment(Request $request)
{
    if (! \Auth::check() &&
        $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        throw \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException::withMessages([
            "comment" => ["Too Many Attempts."],
        ]);
    }

    if (! \Auth::check()) {
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
    }

    // make a comment ?
}

protected function throttleKey(Request $request)
{
    return $request->ip();
}
```

PS i forgot they removed the file in the newest version you might need to include the file manualy.
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ThrottlesLogins.php

Comment: Nope, they didn't remove it. But I thought, I can just override exception in exceptions handler, and add some checking in middleware, like `middleware()->except()`. But overriding the trait, using traits for login, looks like bad way.